# break with label shows error in android

Tags: android

```
public void onClickBackQuestion(View paramView)
{

    if (this.question_number > 0)
    {
        if (!this.testType.equalsIgnoreCase("test"))
            break label93;

        if (this.backQuestionList.size() > 1)
        {
            this.question_number = ((Integer)this.backQuestionList.get(-2 + this.backQuestionList.size())).intValue();
            setQuestion(this.question_number);
            this.backQuestionList.remove(-1 + this.backQuestionList.size());
        }
    }
    return;

    label93:
        int    i = -1 + this.question_number;
    this.question_number = i;
    setQuestion(i);
}
```

In above I  want to check condition that if `testType` is equal to `test`
then I want to break and continue from `label93` but 
I am getting error at declaration of `i` variable.

Please help me out from problem. Thanks in advance

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Syntax error on token "int", delete this token

Comment: You can't have a variable declaration immediately after a label.  http://stackoverflow.com/a/5058025/2598115