# labels used on ordinary method calls - Java

Tags: java, syntax

I was always aware of labels in Java to use for loops such as:

```
myLoop: for(;;) {
  // codez
  break myLoop;
}
```

but just recenlty I found out that this is valid:

```
myLabel: System.out.println("");
```

Why would one want to do that? What is the use of this (if any)?

Comment: Since, `goto` is not implemented in Java (God's sake!) it's just doing nothing :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [using labels in java without "loops"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5057931/using-labels-in-java-without-loops)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The label at the top of a control structure causes execution to resume at the *end* of the control structure once `break myLoop;` is called.

Putting a label on a line that doesn't precede a control structure doesn't do anything. There's no point, but at least it's harmless.

[Labels are described here in the Java language specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.7). There's nothing stopping you from putting a label on any statement. Maybe Java's designers didn't want to restrict which statements could be labeled so that if they introduced a new control structure they wouldn't have to add it to the set of statements that can be labeled.