# Java label? Outer, middle, inner

Tags: java

Please don't worry about the loop but my question is about those keywords: `outer`, `middle`, and `inner`.They are not declared as instance variable, why the IDE let the code compile? I did some search on google, is this java label? some kind of keywords in Java? Thanks guys.

```
public class LoopTest{

public static void main(String[] args){
    int counter = 0;

    outer:
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
        middle:
        for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++){
            inner:
            for(int k = 0; k < 3; k++){{            
            }
                if(k - j > 0){
                    break middle;
                }
                counter++;
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println(counter);
}
```

}

Comment: Yes. Java supports labels.

Comment: Yes, it's a label: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html

Comment: They're not keywords. You can write virtually any word you like. They're just labels to indicate the code block you will `break` out of. You can also use labels with `continue`.

Comment: It's only me or anyone else think this is extremely a bad pratice??? Ok it exists and just leave it there :P

Comment: @JorgeCampos I think it's ok for breaking out of nested loops, but that's about it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Java supports labels. This is described in [this article from Oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html).

So, basically you can have loops with labels and you can use keyword `continue`, `break` and so on to control the flow of the loop.

The following sample illustrates how to use the loop with the `break` keyword. When `break` is invoked it terminates the labeled statement i.e. the statement following `someLabel`

```
someLabel:
    for (i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < 100; j++) {
            if (i % 20 == 0) {
                break someLabel;
            }
        }
    }
```

The `continue` keyword handles labels the same way. When you invoke e.g. `continue someLabel;` the outer loop will be continued.

As [per this SO-question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5057931/using-labels-in-java-without-loops) you can also do constructs like this:

```
BlockSegment:
if (conditionIsTrue) {
    doSomeProcessing ();
    if (resultOfProcessingIsFalse()) break BlockSegment;
    otherwiseDoSomeMoreProcessing();
    // These lines get skipped if the break statement
    // above gets executed
}
// This is where you resume execution after the break
anotherStatement();
```

Personally, I would **never recommend using labels**. Instead I find that the code gets easier to follow if you instead rearrange your code so that labels are not needed (by e.g. break out complex code to smaller functions).

Comment: @wassgren so basically the label is only used in loops correct? with break, or continue.

Comment: @taimeili123 No, that is not entirely true. Check out this SO as well for more info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5057931/using-labels-in-java-without-loops

Comment: What on earth?? I hope they can phase this antipattern out soon

Answer (score 6):

Early in Java, there was a `goto` operator. One day, [James Gosling decided to remove it](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9ei-rbULWoA&t=17m25s). But, it turned out there was still use in allowing you to use `goto` inside loops. So how to do this? Well, with named loops (also known as labeled loops) you could have all the good stuff of breaking out of loops without the downsides of `goto` ridden spaghetti code.

So named loops became a thing, and `break` and `continue` were allowed to break or continue a loop other than their immediate parent.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, these are *labeled statements*, as described in the Java Langage Specification, Java SE 8 Edition, in [section 14.7](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.7):

```
LabeledStatement:
  Identifier : Statement
LabeledStatementNoShortIf:
  Identifier : StatementNoShortIf
```

> The Identifier is declared to be the label of the immediately
>   contained Statement.
>
> Unlike C and C++, the Java programming language has no goto statement;
>   identifier statement labels are used with break or continue statements
>   (§14.15, §14.16) appearing anywhere within the labeled statement.
>
> The scope of a label of a labeled statement is the immediately
>   contained Statement.
>
> It is a compile-time error if the name of a label of a labeled
>   statement is used within the scope of the label as a label of another
>   labeled statement.
>
> There is no restriction against using the same identifier as a label
>   and as the name of a package, class, interface, method, field,
>   parameter, or local variable. Use of an identifier to label a
>   statement does not obscure (§6.4.2) a package, class, interface,
>   method, field, parameter, or local variable with the same name. Use of
>   an identifier as a class, interface, method, field, local variable or
>   as the parameter of an exception handler (§14.20) does not obscure a
>   statement label with the same name.
>
> A labeled statement is executed by executing the immediately contained
>   Statement.
>
> If the statement is labeled by an Identifier and the contained
>   Statement completes abruptly because of a break with the same
>   Identifier, then the labeled statement completes normally. In all
>   other cases of abrupt completion of the Statement, the labeled
>   statement completes abruptly for the same reason.